# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes > (400,2) (400,)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, speech-recognition, feature-extraction

> Dear concerns : I am extracting features from wav , using PLP , this (
>   Pyhton 3.6 -Anaconda Spyder ) after execute i am facing error in this
>   line
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sidekit\frontend\features.py",
>   line 399, in power_spectrum ahan = framed[start:stop, :] * window
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (400,2) (400,)

```
#!usr/bin/python
import numpy.matlib
import scipy
from scipy.fftpack.realtransforms import dct
from sidekit.frontend.vad import pre_emphasis
from sidekit.frontend.io import *
from sidekit.frontend.normfeat import *
from sidekit.frontend.features import *
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np



def readWavFile(wav):
        #given a path from the keyboard to read a .wav file
        #wav = raw_input('Give me the path of the .wav file you want to read: ')
        inputWav = 'C:/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques'+wav
        return inputWav
#reading the .wav file (signal file) and extract the information we need
def initialize(inputWav):
        rate , signal  = wav.read(readWavFile(inputWav)) # returns a wave_read object , rate: sampling frequency
        sig = wave.open(readWavFile(inputWav))
        # signal is the numpy 2D array with the date of the .wav file
        # len(signal) number of samples
        sampwidth = sig.getsampwidth()
        print ('The sample rate of the audio is: ',rate)
        print ('Sampwidth: ',sampwidth)
        return signal ,  rate
def PLP():
        folder = input('Give the name of the folder that you want to read data: ')
        amount = input('Give the number of samples in the specific folder: ')
        for x in range(1,int(amount)+1):
                wav = '/'+folder+'/'+str(x)+'.wav'
                print (wav)
                #inputWav = readWavFile(wav)
                signal,rate = initialize(wav)
                #returns PLP coefficients for every frame
                plp_features = plp(signal,rasta=True)
                meanFeatures(plp_features[0])
#compute the mean features for one .wav file (take the features for every frame and make a mean for the sample)
def meanFeatures(plp_features):
        #make a numpy array with length the number of plp features
        mean_features=np.zeros(len(plp_features[0]))
        #for one input take the sum of all frames in a specific feature and divide them with the number of frames
        for x in range(len(plp_features)):
                for y in range(len(plp_features[x])):
                        mean_features[y]+=plp_features[x][y]
        mean_features = (mean_features / len(plp_features))
        print (mean_features)

def main():
        PLP()

main()
```

Comment: I cannot see the error causing line in the code you posted

Comment: ahan = framed[start:stop, :] * window   Sir  Mortz  when i click or error it opens features.py file and goes in this line

Comment: 'ahan = framed[start:stop, :] * window
        mag = numpy.fft.rfft(ahan, n_fft, axis=-1)
        spec[start:stop, :] = mag.real**2 + mag.imag**2
        start = stop
        stop = min(stop + dec, l)

    return spec, log_energy'

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sidekit\frontend\features.py", line 399, in power_spectrum                                              
    ahan = framed[start:stop, :] * window

Comment: Can you post the entire error message - I am sure it must be pointing to a line in "your code" that is leading to the error in the `features.py` code

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,2) (400,)

Comment: @Mortz  please check my error and help me to solve out , thanks   ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,2) (400,)

Comment: Before your `valueError` line - you should have a line that looks like this - `File "<try.py>", line 7, in <module>` - I am looking for that line

Comment: @Mortz  please check 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sidekit\frontend\features.py", line 921, in plp
    powspec, log_energy = power_spectrum(input_sig, fs, nwin, shift, prefac)

Comment: Welcome, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include a full copy of the error traceback (not just the error), and possibly a sample data so people can copy your code and sample data, reproduce the error and point you to the piece of code you need to fix.

Comment: @Mstaino data files are just wav files , by using this code i want to extract features from wav (16000 Hz) speech file . So you can take any wav file and my code is already given above, So kindly execute it and check error , Thanks a lot for your kind support

Comment: input data is just wav speech file ,  and want to extract features by using PLP

Comment: @Mstaino  after execution of program ,File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sidekit\frontend\features.py", line 921, in plp
    powspec, log_energy = power_spectrum(input_sig, fs, nwin, shift, prefac)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sidekit\frontend\features.py", line 399, in power_spectrum
    ahan = framed[start:stop, :] * window

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,2) (400,)